# Can extract the list of column values using .loc but can not extract a single value from that column in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
def generateRSIDF(prcAllExtractDF: pd.DataFrame):
    rsiAllColumn = np.zeros(0)
    for i in range(0,1):
        rsiDFEach = prcAllExtractDF.iloc[:,i].to_frame()
        rsiDFEach["each"] = pda.rsi(rsiDFEach.iloc[:,0], length=14)
        print(rsiDFEach.loc[:,"each"])
    return rsiAllColumn
```

output:

```
0           NaN
1           NaN
2           NaN
3           NaN
4           NaN
5           NaN
6           NaN
7           NaN
8           NaN
9           NaN
10          NaN
11          NaN
12          NaN
13          NaN
14    71.610546
Name: each, dtype: float64
```

But if I change `.loc` to `.at` to get a single value 71.610546 `print(rsiDFEach.at[14,"each"])`
I get an error said

```
 File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 2270, in __getitem__    
    return super().__getitem__(key)
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 2221, in __getitem__    
    return self.obj._get_value(*key, takeable=self._takeable)
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 3622, in _get_value        
    row = self.index.get_loc(index)
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\range.py", line 387, in get_loc    
    raise KeyError(key) from err
KeyError: 14
```

I just want to extract one single value and store it into a variable

Comment: You still can use `rsiDFEach.loc[14,"each"]`

Comment: @DYZ why is at not working?

Comment: Perhaps your index is a string type?

Comment: See @maya's comment. Also, you have a lot of redundancy in your code. `prcAllExtractDF.iloc[:,i].to_frame()` is simply `prcAllExtractDF.iloc[:,[i]]`, and `rsiDFEach.loc[:,"each"]` is `rsiDFEach["each"]`.

Comment: @DYZ you're right, loc can still be used. And thank u for simplifying my code, I just learned about dataframe 3 days ago and migrate from R to Python so a bit messy.